# How to change file name after upload PHP

Tags: php, html, upload

Currently, my code uploads an image file with the name of the user submitted image. Now obviously I would want to change this to avoid overwriting problems. Now, I've had a look at some other suggestions but I can't seem to get it to work with my code (I've only been learning PHP for a few months). So, could you guys help me? Here's the upload code

```
<?php
$target_dir = "avatars/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

My guess is that I would need to alter the `move_uploaded_file` code? Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like your script already detects if the same name is given.

Comment: Yes it does, however it grabs the name of the original image, I want to alter the image name after upload to avoid images overwriting each other.

Comment: `$target_file` is well that, the name and location. a 'cheap' way to avoid duplicates is to add the timestamp to its name (dont do this on a busy site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$target_dir = "avatars/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

To this:

```
$rand = rand(10000000, 999999999);
$time = time();
$file_name = $rand.$time.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$target_dir = "avatars/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
```

Comment: using the timestamp `time()` with rand or by-itself is another idea.

Comment: @Dagon Yep, that works even better. Will update code to combine the two concepts.

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool No problem. Be sure to use the new code I just updated. This is even more error prone.

Comment: I was just looking for a way to alter the name of the file, now I can change it to match a user name allocated to a member. Essentially I am creating an Avatar Upload system, not sure if this is the best way to go but I haven't had much experience with PHP :)

Comment: Also, is there a way I can completely get rid of the original file name? It seems that `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` gives the random name but also adds the original image name at the end, how would I get rid of this? I've tried removing the `["name"]` part, but I get an error.

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool `$target_file = $target_dir . $user_name_var_here;` (don't forget the file extension)

Comment: @MyNameIsNotSoCool yes you can check my answer below and change `rand(1,99999)` to the name you want the file to be.

Comment: this code renames every image being uploaded without checking if the image exists.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file before you move it.(if it exits)

```
// Check if file already exists
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); //getting the image extension
    $target_file = $target_dir . rand(1,99999).'.'.end($temp);
   $uploadOk = 0;
 }
```

Comment: @Dagon this is before mate are you blind?

Comment: @Dagon it is still in the temporary folder.

Comment: @Dagon you see what my code does, checks if the image exists in the given directory if it does,the give it a new name, then you can use the new name when you move the file.

Comment: lol I'm an idiot :-), but *move* instead of *upload* would be more accurate :-)